# Issue passing 'this' into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, this

Slightly confused by this problem. I have written this function to replace punctuation in input elements:

```js
function punctuationReplace(element){
 var elementToChange = document.getElementById(element);
 elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/\"/g, '');
 elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/\'/g, '');
 elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/&/g, 'and');
 elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/</g, '');
 elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/>/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="IPR_FNM1" name="IPR_FNM1" value="" maxlength="30" size="31" placeholder="Forename 1" onblur="punctuationReplace(this)"/>
```

When I manually run the function in the browser console with the relevant ID as the argument, it works. And when inside the function I add the line `alert(element.id);`, I get an alert containing the correct element ID. So I am confused as to why the above `punctuationReplace` function won't work when I call it using `onblur="punctuationReplace(this)"`.

I'm sure there is a simple solution but no idea what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass in `this` in that fashion, you already have a reference to the element, so no need to call `getElementById`.

```
function punctuationReplace(element){
    var elementToChange = element; //document.getElementById(element);
    elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/\"/g, '');
    elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/\'/g, '');
    elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/&/g, 'and');
    elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/</g, '');
    elementToChange.value = elementToChange.value.replace(/>/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stop using inline event handlers, and the issue solves itself

```
document.getElementById('IPR_FNM1').addEventListener('blur', punctuationReplace, false);

function punctuationReplace(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/("|'|<|>)/g, '').replace(/&/g, 'and')
}
```

Comment: While not using intrinsic event attributes is a good idea, that code won't work unless you also rewrite the `punctuationReplace` function.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Would it work using document.getElementsByTagName('input')?

Comment: @AndyKaufman - It would, but with a for loop, as that gets a nodeList, not a single element

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a reference to a DOM element. It is not a string containing an ID.

You are trying to use it as an argument to `getElementById` but when it is stringified (to `"[Object object]"`) there isn't a matching ID in the document, so you get `null`.

You already have the element. You don't need to search the DOM for it.

Remove the line `var elementToChange = document.getElementById(element);` and change the other references to `element`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` already have an reference to element you want. You don't need to get it again using getElementById. Just put it straight to your variable:

```
  var elementToChange = element;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a `var` just keep using `element`. Like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/0xuf64zb/1

```
function punctuationReplace(element){
    element.value = element.value.replace(/\"/g, '');
    element.value = element.value.replace(/\'/g, '');
    element.value = element.value.replace(/&/g, 'and');
    element.value = element.value.replace(/</g, '');
    element.value = element.value.replace(/>/g, '');
}
```

And indeed stop using inline calls!